# iOS Swift - Using temporary UIView that can be cancelled

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a View Controller that is attached to a Navigation Controller (so any segue out of the View Controller maintains the view hierarchy of the Navigation Controller). How would I go about creating a temporary view that pops up from below that can be cancelled and does *not* conform to the Navigation Controller. For example, the 'Add Event' button in the Apple Calendar App, which brings up a screen that can be cancelled and brought back down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html) or you can just make a custom `UIViewController` and add it to the current view controller as a [child view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:) and present it modally without interfering with the Navigation controller.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the child view controller method?

Comment: The child view controller, is a different view controller so it can have whatever functionality you'd want to have. I'm not really sure I get what you're asking